# _prepareDownloadResponse prepends empty line

Tags: php, collection, xml

This is a simple controller action:

```
    public function indexAction(){
        $from = $this->getRequest()->getParam('from_date');
        if(empty($from) || !($time = strtotime($from))){
            //exception
            return;
        }
        $from = date('Y-m-d', $time) . ' 00:00:00';

        $xml_str = Mage::getModel('formbuilder/formbuilderresult')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('form_id', 1)           
            ->addFieldToFilter('created_time', array('gteq' => $from))->toXml();

        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse(
        'forms.xml',
        $xml_str,
        $contentType = 'application/xhtml+xml',
        strlen($xml_str)
        );
    }
```

Side effect of this, is that the last character is lost in the output.
I know I need to hunt down the extra line in some php file along the way..
Any idea where to start? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the last parameter of the `_prepareDownloadResponse`. It defaults to null, and if is null it is calculated automatically.

```
->setHeader('Content-Length', is_null($contentLength) ? strlen($content) : $contentLength)
```

So your method call should look like this:

```
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse(
    'forms.xml',
    $xml_str,
    'application/xhtml+xml'
);
```

Comment: Yeah It's redundant. But Still the same issue. I need to hunt down that space character...

Comment: @Dror Hmmm...in this case most probably you have a space as output from somewhere else. Make sure you don't have anything before a php open tag `{space_here}<?php` or maybe you closed a php tag in one of the classes and you have a space after it. In the core files there is no case like this. I suggest searching in your custom modules that are loaded in the page you are using.

Comment: Ay! Found it. Thanks for supplying wind for my sails :-)

Comment: @Dror. No problem.